# Android DatePicker year problem

Tags: android

I have a DatePicker in my activity. I want to store the selected date when the user clicks a button like this.

```
Date selectedDate=new Date(dp.getYear(), dp.getMonth(), dp.getDayOfMonth());
```

the problem is when the selected date is like today's: Feb 15 2010

the date returned from the

> selectedDate

is 3910-02-15, so the year is 3910 instead of 2011

what is wrong with this ?

Thanks

Comment: I know this is old, but the constructor I'm using here is deprecated, we can use the new Date(long date) instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, the problem is in the conversion of the selected year value to the date object then displaying it as a string. The date object constructor require the year value minus 1900.

Answer (score 2):

Code is looking fine, but i think when you are trying to display date in the `format` **Feb 15 2010**, at that time problem is being raised.

I suggest check the format that you are using to display your selectedDate.

So you can try as given below:

```
 txtViewDate.setText("Today is " + android.text.format.DateFormat.getLongDateFormat(this).format(new Date())); 
// in your case selectedDate instead of new Date()
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I realized that the constructor of the Date class requires that the year number minus 1900.

Answer (score 1):

Please take  a look at the [example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-datepicker-dialog-example/)