# Android DatePicker and Java's Date

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I was bitten by the problem described here: [Android DatePicker year problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001790/android-datepicker-year-problem) . In a nutshell, Android's DatePicker expects years to be specified in years (2011 is 2011), while Java's Date class starts at 1900 (so 2011 is actually 111).

Is there a better way to intermix Date and DatePickers, other than adding and substracting 1900 when doing the conversions?

Itay.

Comment: This is one of many reasons to never use the terrible legacy classes `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such. Use only *java.time* classes. See the modern solution in [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68398163/642706).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - don't use the deprecated methods in `Date` to work with day/month/year values. `Date` just represents an instant in time - you should use `Calendar` if you want to translate that into some appropriate human breakdown into days, months, years etc - and to apply time zones.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dpYear = 2010, dpMonth = 1, dpDayOfMonth = 15;

        // In DatePicker, the month is indexed starting at 0. Check
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/4467894/10819573 to learn more.
        dpMonth++;

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(dpYear, dpMonth, dpDayOfMonth);
        System.out.println(date);

        // Formatted output
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMMM dd uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2010-02-15
Mon February 15 2010
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Sjp4iN)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>